# Register callback functions on a normal object in Backbone

Tags: backbone.js, underscore.js

I've a object like -

```
var obj = { prop1 : 2,
            prop2 : [] , 
            prop3 : {}
          };
```

Here I don't want make obj as Backbone model like we do

```
var obj = Backbone.Model.extend({
            prop1 :2,
            prop2 : [] ,
            prop3 : {}
          }) ;
```

Then at the same time I want to register callbacks inside Backbone Views whenver prop1 value changes. How can I do this ?
Thanks in advance !!

Comment: Why don't you want to make `obj` a Model? To get events when a property changes, you at least need to make a class that mixes in `Backbone.Events`, and has a `set` method that will handle triggering the right events.

Comment: Because obj has many other properties and methods (not mentioned here) . Only for 2-3 properties I don't want to make it Backbone model.I don't want to remove them as well from obj. I need to register callbacks on prop1 , may be by extending it Backbone.Events .I'm not sure, thats why I posted this ques.What is the best way of doing it?

Answer (score 0):

Yes..the best way to achieve this is by extending an object by Backbone.Events - `_.extend(obj, Backbone.Events);`